# Python remove all entries from list

Tags: python, python-3.x

While initially creating a kind of queue for something else I encountered a weird "problem": If I iterate over the queue and would remove every element via the `list.remove(x)` command I expect the empty list to be the result. But it doesn't, instead in returns basically a sublist as far as I can see.

```
test = ['1', '4', '3', '5']
for entry in test:
    test.remove(entry)
print(test) # Prints ['4', '5']
```

[The official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)  for `list.remove(x)` states:

> Remove the first item from the list whose value is x. It is an error if there is no such item.

I tried it with other examples (i.e. '1', '4', '3' prints '4' or '1', '2', '3' prints '2') but the "error" occurs every time.
Am I missing something obvious? Or is the command supposed to be used in another way?

Comment: @DanielPryden You are right. Voting to close now. Should've done better research...